# Asp:CheckBox checkbox and text are not on the same line

Tags: asp.net

I can't seem to figure out how to get the checkbox and associated text to appear on one line. The text is very short so it doesn't seem to be a width issue.
I tried setting display:inline on the control but when it's rendered, a span is added around the input and label and that has the display:inline. 
If I manually add the display:inline, using the resources view in Chrome, to the resulting label than it's fine. The problem is I don't know how to get the control to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: This behavior is common when mixing ASP.NET Web forms and Twitter Bootstrap. Are you using bootstrap or some other css framework?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to have `display:inline` applied to the `<label>` element that ASP generates to hold the label text, not the control itself. So, for example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    label { display: inline-block; }
</style>
<asp:CheckBox Text="This text appears on same line as checkbox" runat="server" />
```

Comment: It seems the parent div isn't allowing this label to get set.
#sign_up label {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 10px;
color: #536376;
font-size: .9em;
text-align: left;
}
.chsli label {
display: inline; // this is showing a strike-through
}

Comment: This worked:
.chsli label {
    display:inline-block!important;
}

Comment: this worked for me: <asp:CheckBox  TextAlign="Left"  Text="blah"