# asp:CheckBox - prevent text from wrapping below checkbox

Tags: asp.net

I have a  Checkbox with text that is fairly lengthy as shown below. One thing we don't want is for the text to wrap below the checkbox. What I have done to fix this is to put spaces. Also not that part of the text is bold as well:

```
     <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOption1" runat="server" /> <b><u>Option 1</u></b> - Attend in person. This is the best way to gain critical knowledge and express your thoughts and opinions.<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Ample time will be provided for individual discussions during breaks and at the networking reception.
```

Is there a way for the text not to wrap below the checkbox and still have the boldness in the text I need?

Note that I still want the text to wrap but not below the checkbox. Meaning it should wrap below the previous line's text.

Comment: Can you show us the generated html?

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891681/aspcheckbox-checkbox-and-text-are-not-on-the-same-line?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

From the moment you have the text outside of your check box you can warp it with a `span` and `nowrap` style as:

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap;">
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkOption1" runat="server" /> <b><u>Option 1</u></b> - Att ........
</span>
```

if you place your text inside the text of your check box, you can use the `style` attribute as:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkOption1" style="white-space: nowrap;" Text="too long text" />
```

The render html is the same.

Comment: Thanks Aristos. I do want the text to wrap but just not underneath the  checkbox like it does now. The code you gave makes it all on one line which is not her desired effect I was looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Aristos, how about using Div's. Just wondering why the following is not working: <div style="float:left;margin-right:10px"> <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOption1" runat="server"/></div><div style="float:left"> <b><u>Option 1</u></b> - Attend in person. This is the best way to gain critical knowledge and express your thoughts and opinions.  Ample time will be provided for individual discussions during breaks and at the networking reception.</div>
                      <div style="clear:both"></div>

Answer (score 2):

[This link](http://youmohu.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/asp-net-checkbox-text-alignment/) describes a solution. In short:

- do not use the CheckBox Text
- rather, use an extra Label
- set the CheckBox style `float: left`
- set the Label style `display: table`

Comment: Nice and simple

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution: the key is to use display:table and display:table-cell.

Here is the asp.net code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="..." runat="server" CssClass="mobilesubtitle" />
```

and here is the html code produced (relevant parts):

```
<span class="mobilesubtitle">

  <input type="checkbox" name="..." id="...">

  <label for="...">text</label>

</span>
```

All you need to do in css is:

```
span.mobilesubtitle {
    display: table;

}
span.mobilesubtitle > input{
    display: table-cell;

}


span.mobilesubtitle > label {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

---

inline-table also seems to work.